# Automating flask server with Apache. Airflow

Tags: python, docker, flask, airflow

I have a flask server which consists of multiple methods. I am aiming to automate the execution of these methods by using Airflow.
I am thinking of using the following steps:-

1. Setting up Airflow by defining multiple DAGS to call the relevant flask methods  in a pipeline.
2. Deploying Flask Server.
3. Deploying Airflow (using docker-compose).

Mainly, I am thinking to seperate the Airflow and flask servers independently. Do you think this is a good plan? Any other suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a couple of things.

1. Can you run the methods from inside Airflow? For security reasons it is often required to keep some functionality in a different environment/cluster. Reasons for that could be the required database access that you want to give to the Airflow environment.
2. Is this functionality/methods also invoked from other locations or is it solely for Airflow?
3. What other functionality does the flask server have that you can't live without?
4. Are there python dependency conflicts? Even in that case you could use the VirtualEnvOperator of Airflow.

If there is no answer here that is completely blocking you from invoking these methods from inside Airflow, I would vote to do them completely inside Airflow. This will reduce coupling and also reduce the maintenance burden for you in the long term. Besides, Airflow will prevent you from needing to worry about a lot of things, like connectivity, exception codes and callbacks for when something went wrong.